# why a target array with shape (32, 124403) instead of (32, 5)?

Tags: python, keras, text-classification

I want to train a model to classify some sequences of text on **5 categories**.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=num_unique_words, output_dim=128))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))
                
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Outputs:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_10 (Embedding)     (None, None, 128)         15923584  
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirection (None, 128)               98816     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 645       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 5)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 16,023,045
Trainable params: 16,023,045
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And this is `model.fit()`:

```
history = model.fit(
train_sequence,
epochs=1,
#callbacks=callbacks_list,
validation_data=valid_sequence,
workers=11)
```

and I get this error:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 124403) was passed for an output of shape (None, 5) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

nb:

- `batchSize = 32`
- `num_unique_words = 124403`

Comment: Because you did not add a Flatten layer before the Dense

Comment: I add it before but the same error raise; `model.add(Flatten()) model.add(Dense(5))`

Comment: Ah, seems that your target array has a shape that is not correct, why are your targets  (32, 124403)?

Comment: I don't know and it's one of the things that hinder my comprehension.

Comment: if i put num-unique_words in last Dense layer `model.add(Dense(num_unique_words)) ` , it works but whqt happen behind and why i dont know.

Comment: Double-check the labels that you are feeding to the model. Are there just  5 of them (is the shape of them correct?) or somehow accidentally you are feeding the unique words as labels?